# How to resolve MergeException from massive Lucene index writing?

Tags: python, multithreading, merge, lucene, indexing

I have a python script to simply index unicode sentences into a lucene index. And it works fine on the 100 sentences and my 1000 sentences trial. However when i needed to index 200,000 sentences i get a merge error at the 4514th sentence, what is the problem and how can it be solved?

The **Error**:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-4543" org.apache.lucene.index.MergePolicy$MergeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/alvas/europarl/index/_70g.tii (Too many open files)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.ConcurrentMergeScheduler$MergeThread.run(ConcurrentMergeScheduler.java:271)
Traceback (most recent call last):
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/alvas/europarl/index/_70g.tii (Too many open files)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(Native Method)  File "indexer.py", line 183, in <module>

    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:216)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory$FSIndexOutput.<init>(FSDirectory.java:593)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory.createOutput(FSDirectory.java:435)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.TermInfosWriter.initialize(TermInfosWriter.java:91)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.TermInfosWriter.<init>(TermInfosWriter.java:83)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.TermInfosWriter.<init>(TermInfosWriter.java:77)
incrementalIndexing(sfile,tfile,indexDir)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentMerger.mergeTerms(SegmentMerger.java:381)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentMerger.merge(SegmentMerger.java:134)  File "indexer.py", line 141, in incrementalIndexing

    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.mergeMiddle(IndexWriter.java:3109)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.merge(IndexWriter.java:2834)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.ConcurrentMergeScheduler$MergeThread.run(ConcurrentMergeScheduler.java:240)
    writer.optimize(); writer.close()
lucene.JavaError: java.io.IOException: background merge hit exception: _70e:c4513 _70f:c1 into _70g [optimize]
    Java stacktrace:
java.io.IOException: background merge hit exception: _70e:c4513 _70f:c1 into _70g [optimize]
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.optimize(IndexWriter.java:1749)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.optimize(IndexWriter.java:1689)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.optimize(IndexWriter.java:1669)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/alvas/europarl/index/_70g.tii (Too many open files)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:216)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory$FSIndexOutput.<init>(FSDirectory.java:593)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory.createOutput(FSDirectory.java:435)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.TermInfosWriter.initialize(TermInfosWriter.java:91)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.TermInfosWriter.<init>(TermInfosWriter.java:83)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.TermInfosWriter.<init>(TermInfosWriter.java:77)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentMerger.mergeTerms(SegmentMerger.java:381)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentMerger.merge(SegmentMerger.java:134)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.mergeMiddle(IndexWriter.java:3109)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.merge(IndexWriter.java:2834)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.ConcurrentMergeScheduler$MergeThread.run(ConcurrentMergeScheduler.java:240)
```

My code: http://pastebin.com/Ep133W5f

The sample input files:
http://pastebin.com/r5qE4qpt , http://pastebin.com/wxCU277x

Comment: Interestingly, I've tried the same code on my laptop, it works beyond 5k documents but it's just too darn slow. anyone has an idea why would that happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reassigning `filedir` at line 169, without closing the one you made on line 116.  I think that's a mistake, because you don't need to be creating that new one, you can just reuse the old one.  Plus, then you'd be creating it every loop or so and it would just leak handles, since they're never getting closed.

If a few other methods, you'd creating a new `filedir` without closing it, line 106 in `createEmptyIndex` and line 97 in `deleteFromIndex`.

There is another one, that is less obvious, in `retrieveUniqID`.  You're creating `searcher`, but only closing it when the condition `if cont == content:` on line 87 is true.  In the case where there is no match, and you `return None` on line 91, you're never closing that searcher.  In this case, since you're passing a string to the `IndexSearcher` constructor, it's internally creating a `Directory` that you're not closing in certain cases.  You can use a try/finally block to make sure that you always close it, if you'd like.

All of the above calls are made from a main loop in `incrementalIndexing`, so the number of leaked handles increases quickly.

Also, something to consider: all of those classes, the `IndexSearcher`, `IndexReader`, `IndexWriter` and `Directory` are thread-safe, and it's expensive to create new ones each time.  You might be better off with a small redesign to minimize the number of time you'll need to open and close them.  It might actually simply your code, since you could pass around the already created instances which would clean up a lot of the initializing clutter in the different methods.

Since it seems you also want to be able to access the documents you've indexed immediately, I would look into either getting your `IndexReader` (and thus your IndexSearcher as well) via the `IndexWriter.GetReader()` method, or by refreshing the reader, like so: `reader = reader.Refresh()`.

Comment: i've tried closing the directory with writer.getDirectory.close() before writer.close() but it gets mergeError at the same point. `indexDoc` was never used, so it couldnt have been me trying to close filedir on line 43.
But you are right about me wanting to retrieve, add field, delete and re-index documents.

Comment: @2er0 I see, I wasn't looking closely at all of the code.  I took a closer look and updated my answer, with the things I've seen that might be causing the issue.  Also, you don't ever want to close the directory before you close or commit the writer.  The writer needs an active directory to flush the data in memory to disk.  Your merge error might have been a different one, caused by the fact you were trying to flush to a closed directory.

Comment: I have closed every `IndexSearcher`, `IndexReader`,`IndexWriter`, `Directory` instances after i've wrote them but I get the same mergeError at the same point.

I have tried bringing all the above classes out of the main loop and close them after that, but`IndexReader` doesn't get refreshed if i don't close the `IndexReader` after retrieving maxdoc() and if i don't close the `IndexWriter` inside the loop, the addDoc isn't committed.

Comment: I've updated the code at http://pastebin.com/Ep133W5f with all the possible closing of the classes but seems like there is still the same leak and still the same point of being stuck `4514th`

Answer (score 2):

You have "Too many open files" error from Java. Try adding documents in batches then commit & optimize after each batch of (say) 1000 documents. Other solutions exist, but are related to search backend, not your Python script.

Comment: I've been tweaking the writer configurations with setMaxMerge, writer.commit() instead of writer.close(), setMergeFactor. All that didn't work, i guess the only way is to writer in batches, let me try that and get back to you.

Comment: splitting the documents up didnt' help.. same `too many open files`.